# Is the volatile keyword necessary for an atomic property?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety

My class has a property:

```
@property (readwrite, atomic) BOOL IsTrue;
```

My understanding of the `atomic` qualifier is that the `@synthesize`d getter/setter for the property will guarantee serialisation of access from different threads, i.e. if producer thread A is `set`ting the property value it will be allowed to complete the set operation before consumer threads B and C are allowed to `get` the property value (as an aside here, is `atomic` even necessary for a single byte/POD type?).

Does the `volatile` keyword provide any further data integrity?

```
@property (readwrite, atomic) volatile BOOL IsTrue;
```

What I'm specifically driving at is that is there the possibility of consumer threads getting out-of-date values without the use of `volatile`?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5334727/1730272

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there the possibility of consumer threads getting out-of-date
>   values without the use of volatile?

No. From a client's point of view, the property is just a getter/setter method pair. So any client needs to call `objc_msgSend` to set or retrieve a value. Function calls are synchronization points in C so there's no way of getting out of date values (as with direct memory access, where `volatile` might be helpful).

The @synthesize'd accessors will take care of serializing access to the underlying value.

Comment: "Function calls are synchronization points in C" - any source? Thanks.

Comment: @Pang I'm incorrectly using the term "synchronization point" here where I really mean "sequence point". Those are described in the standard (for example C11 in 5.1.2.3 "Program Execution") Quote: [sequence points occur] "Between the evaluations of the function designator and actual arguments in a function call and the actual call". See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf